# Unable to fetch longitude,latitude,etc through geocoding with mapsmyindia

Tags: php, maps, geocoding

Attempt geocoding addresses mapsmyindia api. Here is url for reference:https://www.mapmyindia.com/api/advanced-maps/doc/geocoding-api.

The code is given as below

```
    $json_str = file_get_contents("http://apis.mapmyindia.com/advancedmaps/v1/<?=$key ?>/geo_code?addr=Singanallur Railway Station, Tamil Nadu&pin=");

$obj  = json_decode($json_str);
$data = $obj->lng;
echo $data;
```

Here is the output we got at best.

```
{"responseCode":"200","version":"181.2731","results":[{"houseNumber":"","houseName":"","poi":"Rajalakshmi Mills","street":"Kalimadai Road","subSubLocality":"TVH Vista Heights","subLocality":"Nanjappa Nagar","locality":"Singanallur","village":"","subDistrict":"Coimbatore South","district":"Coimbatore District","city":"Coimbatore;Kovai","state":"Tamil Nadu;TN","pincode":"641005","lat":"10.995464999999999","lng":"77.015103000000096","formatted_address":"Rajalakshmi Mills, Kalimadai Road, TVH Vista Heights, Nanjappa Nagar, Singanallur, Coimbatore South, Coimbatore District, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu","place_id":"FC84F7","type":"POI"},{"formatted_address":"Rajalakshmi Mills, Ramanathapuram, Coimbatore South, Coimbatore District, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu","place_id":"OLIC1G","type":"HOUSE_NAME"},{"formatted_address":"Rajalakshmi Mills High School, Anugraha Gardens, Singanallur, Coimbatore South, Coimbatore District, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu","place_id":"8PXAIC","type":"HOUSE_NAME"},{"formatted_address":"Pankaja Mills, Coimbatore South, Coimbatore District, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu","place_id":"V83JL9","type":"LOCALITY"},{"formatted_address":"Junction Mills, Coimbatore North, Coimbatore District, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu","place_id":"IPCDQT","type":"LOCALITY"},{"formatted_address":"Lakshmi Mills, Coimbatore South, Coimbatore District, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu","place_id":"7X8ZFU","type":"LOCALITY"},{"formatted_address":"GN Mills, Coimbatore North, Coimbatore District, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu","place_id":"KACYTZ","type":"LOCALITY"},{"formatted_address":"Rajalakshmi Nagar, Dindigul, Dindigul District, Dindigul, Tamil Nadu","place_id":"T7Y5DF","type":"LOCALITY"}]}
```

Its working, but throws up data en bloc. That's not the output desired. Require values separately. For instance longitude, latitude should be outputted as separate values.

Look for way out.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual you link to the API returns a JSON String. So to access that data using PHP you need to convert that string into a PHP native data type using `json_decode()`

So for example

```
$json_str = file_get_contents("http://apis.mapmyindia.com/advancedmaps/v1/<?=$key ?>/geo_code?addr=Singanallur Railway Station, Tamil Nadu&pin=");

$obj  = json_decode($json_str);
$data = $obj->lng;
echo $data;
```

Comment: Its not fetching still. I did what you told me to do. Also tried adding more variable like $obj->results->lng but to no avail. What shall we do.

Comment: Please add a `echo $json_str;` and post the output into your question.